# What size breaker is required for a 220v 50w tool?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I have a wood burner with a regular plug, but it said 220v with 50watt. What size breaker do I need?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. First, you should look through the Help section; we aren't a discussion forum. Second, you'll need to provide us with more information; why do you need a "breaker" at all?

Comment: a 100W lightbulb uses twice that power

Comment: then it will draw 25w at 110v, assuming it's a dumb heater circuit. if it's got "smarts" it might not work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Any plug will do, assuming your in a country where 220 is standard.

50watts at 220volts is less than an amp.  (To be exact it’s .22 amps.)